# Oracle "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" using Django with multiple databases/schemas

Tags: python, django, oracle

I recently had to change up my Django back end to accommodate a "restricted database user".

Instead of querying the database using the database admin user that is responsible for making/migrating migrations, a user with SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE on only the necessary tables was created.

I set up the databases in settings.py like so:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'dbname',
            'USER': 'restricted',
            'PASSWORD': '*********',
            'HOST': '*******************',
            'PORT': '****', },
'migrations': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': '*********',
    'HOST': '*********************',
    'PORT': '****',
},
```

}

With the databases set up like this, any queries that are executed from your views go through the "default" restricted user, and the admin user is only there for migrations. To migrate, you would run -

`python manage.py makemigrations` (this command does not change as it does not care about the database user)

and then

```
python manage.py migrate --database=migrations
```

After doing this, none of my views worked, and I discovered the reason why.

The next step that I had to do was to change all of the db_table values in my models.py to match the schema of the new user.

So any db_table values went from this

```
db_table = 'items'
```

to this

```
db_table = '\"schema\".\"items\"'
```

Now this seemed like the solution and most of the code worked, but then I started encountering some `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` errors on very specific, seemingly random views and models. How could changing these db_table values to match the schema only work for *some* of the views/models?

I found the answer to this question after many angry, frustrated hours of searching online and thought I would share it here for anyone who might run into a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not the schema definition, nor was it the 1000 other things I tried, but rather the fact that some of my tables have auto-generate/increment columns as a primary key, and I didn't realize I had to grant access to the sequences responsible for populating these columns to the restricted user.

```
GRANT SELECT ON "SCHEMA"."YOUR_SEQ" TO RESTRICTED_USER
```

Hopefully I can save someone else some time with this :)